# Does Ubuntu Touch multitask like a desktop Ubuntu would?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I recently purchased a nexus 7 and would like to put Ubuntu on it. Regular Ubuntu is no longer supported for this device, only Ubuntu Touch. If I install Ubuntu Touch on my tablet, and plug in a mouse and keyboard, will it function more or less like a desktop version of Ubuntu? ie multiple windows can be open at once on the desktop laying over each other, rather than how Android and other mobile OSes only allow one full screen application to be "running" at once (simplification).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to windowed mode is possible with Unity8 15.04 version.

Comment: With a bit of googling, this is enabled using `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity8 usage-mode Windowed` and disabled using `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity8 usage-mode Staged` feel free to add this to the answer. Cheers!